# Find all possible integers $n$ such that $\sqrt{n + 2} + \sqrt{n + \sqrt{n + 2}}$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find all possible integers $n$ such that $m = \sqrt{n + 2} + \sqrt{n + \sqrt{n + 2}}$ is an integer.

Guess what? This problem is adapted from a recent competition. There have been a solution below for you to check out. I am aware of the fact that there are other solutions that are more practical and suitable in test setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that $$m = \sqrt{n + 2} + \sqrt{n + \sqrt{n + 2}} \ (m \in \mathbb N)$$

$$\iff m - \sqrt{n + 2} = \sqrt{n + \sqrt{n + 2}} \iff (m - \sqrt{n + 2})^2 = n + \sqrt{n + 2}$$

$$\iff m^2 - (2m - \sqrt{n + 2})\sqrt{n + 2} = (\sqrt{n + 2} + 1)\sqrt{n + 2} - 2$$

$$\iff m^2 + 2 = (2m + 1)\sqrt{n + 2} \iff \sqrt{n + 2} = \frac{m^2 + 2}{2m + 1}$$

As an addition, $\dfrac{m^2 + 2}{2m + 1} \in \mathbb Q^+, \forall m \in \mathbb N \implies \sqrt{n + 2} \in \mathbb Q^+$

$\implies \sqrt{n + 2} \in \mathbb N \implies \dfrac{m^2 + 2}{2m + 1} \in \mathbb N \iff \dfrac{4(m^2 + 2) - (2m + 1)(2m - 1)}{2m + 1} \in \mathbb N$

$\iff \dfrac{9}{2m + 1} \in \mathbb N \iff 2m + 1\mid 9 \iff 2m + 1 \in \{1, 3, 9\} \iff m \in \{0, 1, 4\}$

We can set up a table for different value of $m$ and $\sqrt{n + 2}$.

$$\begin{matrix} m&& 0&& 1&& 4\\ \sqrt{n + 2} = \dfrac{m^2 + 2}{2m + 1}&& 2&& 1&& 2 \end{matrix}$$

$\iff n \in \{-1, 2\}$.

Plugging $n \in \{-1, 2\}$ in $m = \sqrt{n + 2} + \sqrt{n + \sqrt{n + 2}}$, we have that $(m,n) = (1, -1)$ and $(m, n) = (4, 2)$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Also, $n=-1$ is valid.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $n+2 = a^2, n + a = b^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers.

If $a > 2$, then $$a^2  = n+2 < n+a = a^2 + a - 2 < a^2 + 2a + 1.$$

This means that $n+a$ cannot be a perfect square as it's bounded between 2 consecutive perfect squares, which is a contradiction. Hence $ 0 \leq a \leq 2$.

If $ a= 0$, then $n = -2$ but $n+a = -2$ is not a perfect square. No solution.
If $a = 1$, then $n = - 1$ and $n+a = 0$ is a pefect square. This gives $m=1$.
If $a=2$, then $n=2$ and $n+a = 4$ is a perfect square. This gives $m=4$.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter approach:

Generally for numbers $m=\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+a}}$ we must have:

$n+a=b^2$

$b^2+b-a=c^2$

If this system of equations, with given a, has integer solutions for n then m is integer.For example $a=3$; $m=\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+3}}$ we have:

$n+3=b^2$

$b^2+b-3=c^2$

It can be seen that with $c=3$ we have:

$b^2+b-3=3^2=9$; or $b^2+b-12=0$ which gives $b=3$ and $b=-4$. With $b=3$ we get $n=6$ and $m=6$, with $b=-4$ we get $n+3=16$ or $n=13$ which gives $m=4+\sqrt{17}$  which is not integer.

In question $a=2$ and  we can search and see that reasonable value of c can only be zero. Other values give irrational numbers for one of terms $\sqrt{n+2}$ or $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+2}}$. Hence we have:

$$b^2+b-2=0$$

Which gives:

$b=1$; $a= 1$; $n=-1$; $m= 1$

$b=-2$;$a= 4$; $n=2$; $m=4$

Comment: There are several mistakes. With $n+2=a$, then $\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n + 2}} = \sqrt{a- 2 +\sqrt{a}}$, but you have it being $\sqrt{a+2 +\sqrt a -2} = \sqrt{a +\sqrt{a}}$ instead. However, your later formula of $b^2 + b - 2$ handles this correctly. Nonetheless, you don't explain why you can assume that $b^2 + b - 2 = 0$. Finally, with your last $2$ lines, if $b = 1$, then $a = 1$, not $a = \pm 1$, and if $b = -2$, then $a = 4$, not $a = \pm 2$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thanks for correcting comment. I edited my answer and explained why second term is equal to zero.

Comment: Your welcome. However, you still haven't corrected my first stated mistake of not correctly stating $\sqrt{a - 2 + \sqrt{a}}$. Also, once again, if $b = -2$, then $a = 4$ (and, thus, $n = 2$), but you have it as $a = 2$.